# Is it idiomatic to use "fixate" to imply an intensified focus on something, especially in technical writings?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, idiomatic-language

I have done some researches and I think "fixate" imparts a taste of obsession in addition to that of being attentive of something.

Would "fixate" imply an intensified focus on something?

For instance, in an technical/scientific description as

> We fixate on the major components influencing the computation time.

Answer (score 1):

Fixating implies an obsessive preoccupation with something. Focusing implies concentrating on something. Very similar though.

[Wikidiff](https://wikidiff.com/focus/fixate) has a good summation.

You might also like [this](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/fixate) example and definition from Merriam-Webster